# Why can I only use some capital greek letters inside my equations?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, greek

For example:

```
\begin{equation}
\delta % ok
\Delta % ok
\epsilon % ok
\Epsilon % error
\end{equation}
```

Comment: I also ran into this problem today. The capital letter $E$ is not what I wanted. I wanted the symbol $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: Don Knuth spent some time to explain the TeX logo.  I think it still makes a good read.  Ironically, what we call "Greek" letters should be called Byzantine script, as ancient Greeks (i.e., Archimedes and his likes never used it).  However, the question is legitimate and dismissing it as "just write latin E" is a bad way to answer it.  This does not explain, for example, what happens when you typeset a Greek book in TeX.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Uppercase epsilon is E.

```
\begin{equation}
\delta % ok
\Delta % ok
\epsilon % ok
E        % ok
\end{equation}
```

Comment: wow and i thought c++ was inconsistent

Comment: Yeah, as much as I love LaTeX for its typesetting skill, it makes so little sense internally.

Comment: `unicode-math` has `\Alpha`, etc. defined, so this will be more consistent in the future.

Comment: The uppercase epsilon *is* E, so I don't see how this is inconsistent. This visual similarity (identicalness, actually) is a feature of the scripts themselves: what would you expect from an "uppercase epsilon" if not the letter E?

Comment: I think this is one to learn from for LaTeX3: on semantic grounds there should be a macro here, even though in the default fonts it doesn't show up visually.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature: It will prevent you from using confusing letters in an equation.

Comment: TeXnically speaking $\epsilon$ (or $\delta$ for that matter) has no uppercase version.  To be sure try \MakeUppercase{\epsilon} or \MakeUppercase{\delta} and see the system going cross.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR the same could be said about (lower case) $\upsilon$ (or $\nu$, if you like the horrible times) which looks exactly like a $v$ in computer modern.  Yet both $\upsilon$ (or $\nu$ for that matter) exist.  Is TeX a cryptoanticapitalist (i.e., covertly favouring lower case against upper case)?

Comment: The fact two letters from different character sets (alphabets) look alike doesn't necessarily mean they're the same characters. K (capital k) and Κ (capital kappa - κ) look the same, but they're different characters.

Comment: @OskarLimka Tell that to the Greeks that there is no uppercase letter for epsilon. ;)

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś that's exactly my point, modern Greeks always show a degree of puzzlement on how non-Greeks pronounce, write... and typeset Greek letters. What we call a "Greek" letter in TeX is just a math symbol (derived from classical Greek). When one's using $\epsilon$ is not the same as \textit{ε} for TeX, even if you italicize the latter and make it look like one.

Answer (score 34):

To quote from The LaTeX Companion (p. 527),

> Those capital Greek letters not present in this table are the letters that have the same appearance as some Latin letter. Similarly, the list of lowercase Greek letters contains no omicron because it would be identical in appearance to the Latin *o*. Thus, in practice, the Greek letters that have Latin look-alikes are not used in mathematical formulas.

So basically, nobody would use a capital epsilon in a formula because it'd be visually indistinguishable from E.

If this bothers you, you could define the missing macros for Greek letters, e.g.

```
\newcommand{\Alpha}{A}
\newcommand{\Beta}{B}
\newcommand{\Epsilon}{E}
```

and so on.

Comment: I remember in a class on spinor methods discovering with some alarm that the basis spinors were denoted omicron and iota, with the two components denoted by super- and sub-script 0 and 1.  Since the spinors were indexed by capitals, it made a page of `$o_0^{A'} \iota_A^1$`, handwritten, rather challenging to re-read.  When the lecturer remarked in an aside that this was a rather exquisite in-joke, he only narrowly escaped being collectively throttled by the class.

Comment: My measure theory lecturer wanted to use `$\mathbb{C}$` for something other than the complex numbers, but we shouted him down. There were still at least 4 near-indistinguishable "M"s...

Comment: Use \providecommand instead, that way it's forward compatible in case these commands are defined in the future.

Comment: Except, of course, for the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), the [H theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/84743/30935), and certain [Gegenbauer functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_Gegenbauer).

Comment: I can't see the difference between $\upsilon$ and $v$.

Comment: *"Thus, in practice, the Greek letters that have Latin look-alikes are not used in mathematical formulas."* Wrong! The symbol for [Shannon's entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) in information theory is a Greek uppercase eta. It's not a Latin uppercase h. The point is: when you search for an uppercase greek eta in a document, and you know it must be there, because it is used in the formula for entropy, then you will not find it if a Latin uppercase h is used instead. And if you search for Latin uppercase h, you will find thousands of them if the document is long

Answer (score 14):

David's point is worth underlining:

> So basically, nobody would use a capital epsilon in a formula because it'd be visually indistinguishable from E.

If you wanted to type something actually in Greek, then you would use one of the packages designed for that (search on CTAN for "greek" to get an idea of what's available).  The Greek letters that are defined in unadorned LaTeX should not be viewed as letters but as mathematical symbols.  So α should be viewed in the same regard as something like ≤.  This is underlined by their appearance: just as "x" looks different in text and in maths, so "α" will look different in text and in maths.  So the fact that "Α"  (`\Alpha`) and the like are missing is simply because regarded as a symbol, it's just "A", and *no-one* would ever write `\Alpha` because they can just write `A` and the fact of calling it "Alpha" adds nothing.  Compare this with "x" (`x`) and "×" (`\times`) where the different names actually mean something (variable versus operator).

So, in summary, if you want to type `\Epsilon` and the system complains then you are doing something wrong: either you are trying to type something in Greek without loading a proper Greek alphabet, or you are distinguishing in the source code something that will be indistinguishable in the actual document.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers have made this fairly clear: a capital epsilon is identical to a capital E, so there's no need for a separate LaTeX command.  However, there is a point missing from the answers above.  Roman letters (by which I mean letters from the Roman alphabet) are conventionally set italic in math mode, to make clearer the distinction between maths and text.  But Greek letters are set upright by default (though some journals deviate), because there's no distinction that needs making (assuming you're not writing in Greek).  So if you really want a capital epsilon, and you want a consistent look for all your capital Greek letters, you should use \mathrm{E}.

Comment: That's not true. The Greek letters are typeset italic. There's a package to typeset them upright: [`upgreek`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/upgreek.html)

Comment: Hmm, that's strange; mine are definitely upright, and I can't imagine that I'm calling upgreek without knowing it.  Could this be a result of font selection?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmirror.ctan.org%2Fmacros%2Flatex%2Fcontrib%2Funicode-math%2Funicode-math.pdf&rct=j&q=unicode-math%20pdf&ei=QRGkTbzGJo_NswayrcyWCA&usg=AFQjCNGXfNrx_Iw1NWZyGBvm1mBnrAGDQQ&cad=rja) at section 5.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my wild guess is that such macros are missing because CM has no such glyphs to begin with, Knuth's Greek is meant for use in math and not for running text and thus there were no point in duplicating glyphs that are visually indistinguishable from Latin counterparts.