# Which package includes \Rho? (Big rho)

Tags: packages, letters, greek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)
>   [Why can I only use some capital greek letters inside my equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/why-can-i-only-use-some-capital-greek-letters-inside-my-equations)

I want to use the big rho (`\Rho`) in my document but can not find a package which provides that char. It is not in the default math package.

Is there a package with extended greek letters? Like here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#List_of_Mathematical_Symbols

Comment: Big rho looks like a capital "P"…

Comment: How about: `\def\Rho{P}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I took the liberty to format you post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help). We do not include "thanks" nor signature to our post, signature already appears in the bottom right corner and you can thank the others by upvoting and accepting their answers.

Comment: @percusse: That's a good idea. I'd suggest just mentioning the link in a comment then ("This question might be interesting to you if you're looking for a specific symbol ..."), unless it actually is a duplicate.

Comment: Available greek capitals are `\Gamma,\Lambda,\Sigma,\Psi,\Delta,\Xi,\Upsilon,\Omega,\Theta,\Pi,\Phi` the rest is, as far as I know, the same with the Latin capitals. However for a more comprehensive look-up options for other specific symbols please see [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As @Seamus correctly points out, capital Rho has the same glyph as capital P. You can put `\newcommand{\Rho}{\mathrm{P}}` into your preamble to make the macro `\Rho` avialable. The usage of `\mathrm` is necessary if you use default math alphabets, because all greek capitals are typeset in up-right font.

List of those Greek letters whose capital variants coincide with latin capitals:

```
Α α alpha
Β β beta
Ε ε epsilon
Ζ ζ zeta
Η η eta
Ι ι iota
Κ κ kappa
Μ μ mu
Ν ν nu
Ο ο omicron
Ρ ρ rho
Τ τ tau
Υ υ upsilon
Χ χ chi
```

Plus remember that lowercase omicron looks exactly like `o` (and should be typeset by normal math font, i.e., without `\mathrm`).