# Capital and small nu

Tags: greek

I couldn't figure out the command for Capital Nu as shown in the picture. I tried `\Nu` but it doesn't work.[image]

I googled but found nothing helpful.

Comment: It's not a capital nu… because *this* is a capital: `N`. It is probably a large-size lowercase nu or a math calligraphic V.

Comment: Could you show me the latex commands? Because I am new to LaTeX and don't understand a bunch of words you just use.

Comment: math calligraphic means try this: `\mathcal{V}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some Greek capital letters look the same as Latin capitals and therefore don't have unique commands. Nu is one of them. The list of these Greek capitals is available from several sources, including

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/14751-greek-alphabet-and-latex-commands-not-a-question
and 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49602/61108

From the linked TeX.SX answer the list is

```
Α α alpha
Β β beta
Ε ε epsilon
Ζ ζ zeta
Η η eta
Ι ι iota
Κ κ kappa
Μ μ mu
Ν ν nu
Ο ο omicron
Ρ ρ rho
Τ τ tau
Υ υ upsilon
Χ χ chi
```

Just use `N` for capital nu.

Comment: Thank you. Let suppose that I want to enlarge $\nu$, what command should I use?

Comment: `$\tilde{\mathcal{V}}$`

Comment: I think my question is miss leading. I should be asking what is the command for Script V?

Answer (score 8):

It is certainly a math calligraphic V. Here is the formula, reproduced as faithfully as possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\I{\mathrm i}
\newcommand\E{\mathrm e}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
& \widetilde{\mathcal{V}} &{} = -\hbar \Omega \Bigl\{ &\sigma_ + \E^{-\I(\Delta t-\varphi)}\bigl[1 + \I\eta(b\E^{-\I\nu t} + b^{\dagger}\E^{\I\nu t})\bigr]\Bigr. \\
  & & \Bigl. {}+{} &\sigma_ -\E^{\I(\Delta t-\varphi)}\bigl[1 - \I\eta(b\E^{-\I\nu t} + b^{\dagger}\E^{\I\nu t})\bigr]\Bigr\}. 
 \end{alignat*}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...and `$\tilde{\mathcal{V}}$` would give you the tilde above the `V`

Comment: Yes, I've just seen (and corrected) that.

Comment: Your `\widetilde` looks better. Interestingly the original seems to have just used a narrow tilde though.

Comment: Many people think `\widetilde` is for a group of several letters, but actually it is better, in my opinion, for single wide letters (`m` or capital letters).