# $\zeta$ works $\Zeta$ does not

Tags: math-mode, greek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can I only use some capital greek letters inside my equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/why-can-i-only-use-some-capital-greek-letters-inside-my-equations)

Refering to http://wikieducator.org/Help:LaTeX_Symbol_Tables_-_Mathematics, I am trying to enter upper case Zeta into my tex file. When I enter $\zeta$ it compiles the code but when I say $\Zeta$ with upper case Z with a expectation that it would lead to upper case zeta, it does not compile. Am I missing something?

I am using Kile (Version 2.0.85) under Ubuntu (Version 11.04) and using Latex to compile the code. All other symbols like Uppercase Omega are not causing any problem.

Comment: The uppercase Zeta is Z, so simply write `Z`.

Comment: Ohh is it? I am just being stupid. I should have thought about it. I just copied the code on the web link mentioned above.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/why-can-i-only-use-some-capital-greek-letters-inside-my-equations

Comment: If you like, edit that Wiki page and correct it, if it's publicly editable. I made an answer from my comment.

Comment: yes I think I should

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The uppercase Zeta is Z, so simply write `Z`. You may define `\Zeta` yourself, such as

```
\newcommand{\Zeta}{Z}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\Zeta}{\mathrm{Z}}
```

depending on your needs.